# How do I pass parameters to tests in an Automake input file?

Tags: automake

In my `Makefile.am`, I have the following test:

```
TESTS += tests/test1
check_PROGRAMS += tests/test1
tests_test1_SOURCES = tests/test1.c
tests_test1_CPPFLAGS = ...
tests_test1_LDADD = ...
```

`test1` is compiled and run when `make check` is invoked. How should `Makefile.am` be modified to pass a command line argument to test1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments to tests.

Instead of

```
TESTS += tests/test1
```

do

```
TESTS += tests/test1.test
EXTRA_DIST += tests/test1.test
```

where `tests/test1.test` is an executable shell script that will run your program with any argument you wish:

```
#!/bin/sh
tests/test1 args... < $srcdir/tests/distributed-input-file
```

Comment: +1 for the answering my rather different question of whether there was a way to use `$srcdir` in test scripts - turns out it's just that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass parameters via the environment. This is handy when you want to pass different parameters in different runs of `make check`.

Say you have `tests/test1.test` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
tests/test1 $TEST_FLAGS < $srcdir/tests/distributed-input-file
```

Now, you can run the following:

```
$ TEST_FLAGS=--verbose make check
```

And the `--verbose` flag would be passed to your test program whenever you want it to display extra info for debugging purposes.